# How can I make transparent black background with non transparent text in front?

Tags: html, css

I would like the text in `h1` to have a transparent black background. I can't get the background color to appear let alone make it transparent.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

h1 span {
    background-color: Black;
    color: DeepSkyBlue;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 10s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    50% {color: CornflowerBlue;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    50% {color: CornflowerBlue;}
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>The Last Will and Testament ofEric Jones</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: set `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` on whatever you want to have a semi-transparent background. That will add a 50% transparent black background.

Comment: thanks. but my background isn't even showing. am I doing something wrong with my css? I've also tried class (h1 class="textDisplay" and changed the h1 span to .textDisplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the background on the `h1`...not the span.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
h1 span {
  color: DeepSkyBlue;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 10s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  50% {
    color: CornflowerBlue;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  50% {
    color: CornflowerBlue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><span>  
The Last Will and Testament of
Eric Jones</span></h1>
```

Comment: I found that there was a competing css  file that was overriding my values

Answer (score 1):

You can use rgba for your background color :

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 span {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: DeepSkyBlue;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 10s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  50% {
    color: CornflowerBlue;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  50% {
    color: CornflowerBlue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><span>  
The Last Will and Testament of
Eric Jones</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see the sample code running but when i copy your css and place it in my css, I do not even see a background appear

Answer (score 1):

Set background-color with rgba(), where "alpha" is the opacity. You can get it work here: https://jsfiddle.net/0L1daf1v/

```
h1 span {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: DeepSkyBlue;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 10s infinite;
}
```